# How to specify invocation of a class method as entry behavior of a state in UML

Tags: uml, state-machine

How can the following be expressed in UML:

> I have a class, whose behavior is modeled as a state machine. On entry
>   to a particular state in that state machine, I want to invoke an
>   operation (method) of the class instance.

I'm trying to figure out the formal way to capture the relationship described above. I know that entry behaviors of a state can be of different types (e.g., FunctionBehavior). Classes can have Operations which are essentially specifications for a function (like a function typedef). I'm confused as to how to specify a function as implementing a particular Operation, and then have it be invoked from potentially multiple state entry behaviors.

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/bank-atm-uml-state-machine-diagram-example.html?context=stm-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing Superstructure for 2.5 (chap. 14.2.3.4.3 p. 307):

> **State entry, exit, and doActivity Behaviors**
>
> A State may have an associated entry Behavior. This Behavior, if defined, is executed whenever the State is entered through an external Transition. In addition, a State may also have an associated exit Behavior, which, if defined, is executed whenever the State is exited.
>   A State may also have an associated doActivity Behavior. This Behavior commences execution when the State is entered (but only after the State entry Behavior has completed) and executes concurrently with any other Behaviors that may be associated with the State, until:
>
> - it completes (in which case a completion event is generated) or
> - the State is exited, in which case execution of the doActivity Behavior is aborted.
>
> The execution of a doActivity Behavior of a State is not affected by the firing of an internal Transition of that State.

That means you can define an operation in the class which is executed when the state is entered. You show it this way:

[image]

**Edit**: Just copying Geert's comment below to make it water proof :-)

> The UML specs are quite specific saying that the state has an associated Behavior. The Behavior might be the method of an operation but it doesn't have to be. Since Behavior itself is an abstract meta-class it can be any of Activity, OpaqueBehavior, FunctionBehavior, Interaction, StateMachine or ProtocolStateMachine

Comment: Thomas, I don't think that is entirely correct. An operation is not a `Behavior`, but a `BehavioralFeature`

Comment: @GeertBellekens "A BehavioralFeature is implemented (realized) by a Behavior" so the above can be seen as a "shortcut". I guess you still can read it that the operation (BehavioralFeature) is performed by the entry (Behavior) which represents a realization of the latter.

Comment: The UML specs are quite specific saying that the state has an associated `Behavior`. The `Behavior` might be the `method` of an operation but it doesn't have to be. Since `Behavior` itself is an abstract meta-class it can be any of `Activity`, `OpaqueBehavior`, `FunctionBehavior`, `Interaction`, `StateMachine` or `ProtocolStateMachine`

Comment: I don't quite see how your edit addresses @GeertBellekens comment. Since an Operation by itself is not associated with a body of code, an entry Behavior being represented by an Operation doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: This is simply a practical approach. Though they might be a different pair of shoes the above shown `someOperation` can well be a method of the class for which the state is defined. And simply, you match it by name. What else would you do to implement behavior if not with some operation defined in your class?